# Existence of rational curve in a Fano manifold of a given spilitting type

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective Fano variety of dimension $n$ with Picard number one over the field of complex numbers and different from the projective space. Let the tangent bundle of $X$ is not nef.

Question: Does there exist a rational curves $l$ in $X$  such that $ TX\vert_l = \oplus_{i=1}^{n-1} \mathcal{O}(a_i) \oplus \mathcal{O}$, for some  $ a_1, a_2, ..., a_{n-1} > 0$ ?

I think it is always possible. The reason for my claim is the following:
Let $d$ be the degree of a curve in the minimal rational component. Then for a general curve $l, TX\vert_l= \mathcal{O}(2) \oplus \mathcal{O}(1)^{d-2} \oplus \mathcal{O}^{n-d+1}$. Let $l$ be such a rational curve and a curve $C$ is obtained as a composition of $l \to l \to X$, where $l \to l$ is a degree $m= n-d+1$ degree map. Then $TX\vert_C=\mathcal{O}(2m) \oplus \mathcal{O}(m)^{d-2} \oplus  \mathcal{O}^{n-d+1}$. Then by a result of GEOFFREY SMITH ://people.math.harvard.edu/~gsmith/P1Trees.pdf, Theorem 2, there is a rational curve $C^{'}$ such that $TX\vert_{C^{'}}= \mathcal{O}(2m) \oplus \mathcal{O}(m)^{d-3} \oplus \mathcal{O}(m-1) \oplus \mathcal{O}(1) \oplus \mathcal{O}^{n-d}$ which specializes to $C$. Repeating this inductively we, get the desired decomposition.

Please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: You want to know if this is true for each tuple $a_i$ or for at least one tuple?

Comment: For at least one tuple $a_i, i=1,. . . {n-1}$. What I need is that the restriction is not ample exactly at one summand

Comment: Something is wrong with that argument (possibly in Geoff Smith’s theorem — I will check it out).  For smooth Fano hypersurfaces with Fano index equal to $2$ the multiple covers of minimal free rational curves deform only to other multiple covers of minimal free rational curves.  That is in my thesis (it is just a parameter count).

Comment: I looked at Smith's article, and he does not prove anything like the result you state.  He proves there is an abstract deformation of $TX|_C$ as a vector bundle to the vector bundle that you wrote, but he does not claim that you can obtain this abstract deformation by a deformation of the morphism from $C$ to $X$ via pullback of $TX$.

Comment: Could you please send me your thesis ?